# How to merge two data frames and keep not all matches?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, merge

there are 2 dataframes:
d1:

```
id    city     position
1     NY       manager
2     NY        manager
3     NY        manager
4     NY        Engineer
5     LA        Engineer
6     LA        Designer
```

d2:

```
team    city     position
a           NY       manager
a          NY        manager
b          NY        Engineer
b          LA        Engineer
```

I need to left join d1 and d2 by "city" and "position", but i don't want to keep all matches. d1's shape should not change. but when i do this:

```
d1.merge(d2, how = "left", on = ["city", "position"])
```

I get all possible matches, but what i need is to select some of them and keep d1's shape same

so desired result is:

```
team    city     position        id  
a           NY       manager      1
a          NY        manager      2
b          NY        Engineer     4
b          LA        Engineer     5
```

and df1 must be updated and become like this:

```
id    city     position
3     NY        manager
6     LA        Designer
```

how could I do it? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
desired_output = d2.merge(d1, how = "left", on = ["city", "position"]).drop_duplicates()
d1 = d1[~d1['id'].isin(desired_output['id'].values)]
```

The out will look like the following.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think to updating both data frames would be the efficient way instead of merge.

Here, I have loop over `d2` and perform two step:

- filter table with similar city and position, take first row id, and update d2
- update d1 by droping the row which contains received id

Code:

```
d2['id'] = None
def up( c,p):
    global d1
    id_val = list(d1[(d1['city'] == c) & (d1['pos'] == p)]['id'])
    d1 = d1[~d1['id'].eq(id_val[0])].reset_index(drop=True)
    return id_val[0]

 
d2['id'] = d2.apply(lambda r: r.id if r.id else up( r.city, r.pos), axis=1)
    
print(d2)
print(d1)
```

Output:

d1

```
   id   city    pos
0   3   NY     M
1   6   LA     D
```

d2

```
  team  city pos    id
0   a   NY   M      1
1   a   NY   M      2
2   b   NY   E      4
3   b   LA   E      5
```